# How to cancel source control sync loop in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I synchronize my git code, sometimes it is because of network problems that I keep loading.

Because I am a connected private network, I am often disconnected. This problem has perplexed me for a long time, and every development will encounter.

How can I cancel this operation?
[image]

Comment: have you tried the `Git: Refresh` command in the command palette? or does that have the same problem? What do you see in the Output Panel's Git channel?

Comment: I can't find the place you said, can you answer, screenshot to show the specific operation? You can disconnect the network to test when you submit, so you can reproduce the problem.